# ASP.Net Webforms with ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

I am creating an ASP.Net Webform page to use the ReportViewer control so our users can view SSRS reports inside a web page.

I have created one report and it worked great.  I am in the process of doing a second report, which is mostly just a copy / paste of the first report, but for some reason, I am unable to display the report in my page (see screen shot).

I do not get any error in the code, nor does the SSRS report seem to throw an error.  It seems to load as I get the two scroll bars shown in the screen shot after I hit "view report" button, but for some reason, there is no report shown.  The report works, as I tried it on the SSRS server itself and have no problems.  Anyone know what I might be missing or causing this?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > General, Uncheck Enable Just My Code then check if you can see the exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Report viewer does not load, showing blank space - running local RDLC files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754544/report-viewer-does-not-load-showing-blank-space-running-local-rdlc-files)

Comment: try checking the console error from browser

Comment: Thanks guys.  These suggestions showed me the error.  I will admit it wasn't an overly obvious error, as it wasn't any execption being thrown, but the parameter "State" was showing "MissingValidValue" which led me down the path, but I wouldn't have been able to get there without knowing these debug tricks and sites.  Appreciate it.